# Automating Raster Clipper for single raster but multiple masks using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I have a large raster that I need to clip into many smaller tiles, however as there are nearly 200 tiles it will take too long to clip each tile individually and I need to automate the process.

The following python script will clip multiple rasters with a single extent box however, I need to clip a single raster with multiple masks.

Is it possible to simply adjust the parameters of this script to accomplish what I need?

```
# input variables

# where to save clipped rasters
outputDir = "/home/user/Desktop/clip"

# upper left point
UX, UY =  xxxxxx , xxxxxx

# lower right point
LX,  LY = xxxxxx , xxxxxx

# actual script
import os
lddLrs = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()
for lyr in lddLrs:
 if (lyr.type()==QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer):
  os.system("gdal_translate -projwin " + str(UX) + " " + str(UY) + " " + str(LX) + " " + str(LY) + " -of GTiff " + str(lyr.source()) + " " + outputDir + "/" + str(lyr.name()) + ".tif")
  qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(str(outputDir + "/" + lyr.name() + ".tif"), str(lyr.name() + "_clip.tif"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same without pyqgis directly from processing tools. Create a polygon grid specifying the x,y sizes to be equal to the extent of each smaller tile using Vector Grid tool from `Vector -> Research tools -> Vector Grid tool`

[image]

Then Clip raster by Mask Layer from `Processing toolbox -> OGR/GDAL -> [GDAL] Extraction -> Clip raster by Mask Layer`

- Select the raster file
- Select the vector grid file created in the previous step
- Click on iterator to iterate over each small polygon in the grid vector

[image]

Make sure that both raster and vector grid have the same projection (CRS)